# iOS: How to make items in local keychain persist after migration?

Tags: ios, swift, migration, backup, keychain

In my application I use keychain with availability set to Always. In documentation it says that in this case the item will migrate to a new device when using encrypted backups. But what about device-to-device migration? I don't think that it is considered as an encrypted backup.
Is there a way to always migrate my keychain items no matter what method of restoring is used? Considering there is no way to force users to enable iCloud Keychain.
Thanks!